# Validating a PKI certificate signed by a Sub-CA which is unknown to the VPN Gateway, but signed by a trusted root

Tags: certificate, vpn, cisco, pki

I have an architecture where there is a single root CA and multiple sub-CAs, one each for a number of domains.  Each domain has a VPN Gateway (Cisco router) which has a root CA trustpoint configured and one for the sub-CA in it's domain.  It is able to successfully validate certificates presented by clients which are signed by the sub-CA in it's domain.  What I'd like to be able to do is to have the VPN Gateway successfully validate certificates from VPN clients which have been signed by a sub-CA in a different domain.  Each sub-CA certificate is signed by the root of course.

This scenario has been successfully implemented in a Strongswan Client -> Strongswan VPN Server, however we've been unable to get it to work with Cisco AnyConnect -> Cisco Router.  The Cisco doesn't seem to know enough to request the additional certificate information from the client.  It simply fails to find an appropriate trustpoint and denies the connection.

Has anyone done anything like this and could offer some advice?

Thanks!

Comment: The router shouldn't *have* to search for the subordinate CA.  If your client is configured correctly, it should present all subordinate with its handshake.

Comment: So you're saying the AnyConnect client should be presenting it's certificate as well as the Subordinate CA and Master CA?  I'm having trouble finding this in the configuration of the client (linux client).

Comment: Yes.  If you read RFC 5246 Section 7.4.6 you'll see that it describes that the client certificate is sent using the same structure as for a server certificate - "This message conveys the server's certificate **chain** to the...".  Maybe create a certificate bundle from the end-entity and subordinate CA certificates.  The 'Master' (the trust anchor) should be configured separately; I believe it uses NSS which is the library used by Firefox and Chrome, so if the root is trusted there, it should be OK for your AnyConnect.

Comment: Could this be a simple as concatenating the client->sub->master certificates into the one .pem file which AnyConnect is presenting to the server?

Comment: Client and subordinate, yes.  Your 'master' (by which I assume you mean the root CA certificate) should be added as a separate entity to the trust anchor store of the server.  How that's done depends on the SSL/TLS library and the distro you're using.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have as trust anchor a self-signed, root CA "R", and two domain, intermediate CAs "A" and "B" signed by R.

Then you have client certificate "alice" signed by "A", and client certificate "bob" signed by B.

Then when alice comes to her domain, there is R and A installed, and her certificate verifies.

But when she goes to bob's domain, there is R and B, and her certificate does not verify, even though it is signed by A and A is signed by R.

This would be because A is not installed in bob's domain, or, alice did not sent A.

However, the TLS client of alice could send certificate "alice" along with intermediate certificate "A". In this case, at bob's domain where there is R and B, B is not used. The incoming client certificate chain contains "alice" and A, and alice is signed by A, and A is signed by R, and alice is verified. (There is no reason for alice to send a copy of R -- it would not be used anyway.)

You have to look at your client configuration. It is probably as simple as ensuring that A is installed on the client, in which case the client TLS library could attach it to the chain on the way out. That is the first thing I would try. Install A on the client alice is using to contact bob's domain. It does not need to be installed as a trusted root -- just as an intermediate CA in the certificate store that alice uses when she connects.

Comment: I've tried doing this.  It's a Centos 6.6 server, so I used the standard methods I found online for installing new certificates.  No luck unfortunately.